# Laravel how to upload/download files to Amazon S2 using KMS

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I am trying to upload/download files from amazon s3 using KMS, although i have implemented this without using KMS by the following code,

```
$filePath = "users/" . $user_id . "/". $name;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
$fileName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath);
```

Now I am trying to add the KMS feature to my bucket, create my key, and implement the bucket policy. Still, I can't get the possible syntax for uploading/downloading files using KMS for laravel/PHP; I am a newbie here for s3.

Comment: First you'll need to encrypt the objects and then you'll need to upload them to S3 Bucket. To have the aws kms in laravel, you can refer this link [AWS KMS](https://blog.deleu.dev/swapping-laravel-encryption-with-aws-kms/)

Comment: Amazon S3 uses KMS by default as server side encryption. So you are probably there already. If you want client side encryption because your application is not deployed at aws or there's some other reason you should take a look at https://blog.deleu.dev/swapping-laravel-encryption-with-aws-kms/ as Haridarshan said